# Managing Dependencies of Reflected Dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, reflection, dependencies, mef, dependency-management

I presently work with a large solution, containing about 100 projects.  At least 10 of the projects are executable applications.  Some of the library projects are imported as plugins via MEF and reflection rather than with direct references.  If a needed plugin's own dependencies are not copied to the output or plugin directory of the executable project using it, we'll get reflection errors at runtime.

We've already tried or discussed the following solutions, but none of them seem like a good fit:

1. **"Hard" References**: Originally, we had the executable projects reference other projects they needed, even if they were going to ultimately be imported as optional plugins.  This quickly fell out of favor with team members who needed to make builds that excluded certain plugins and liked to unload those projects to begin with.  This also made it difficult to use Resharper or other tools to clean unused references and remove obsolete third party libraries without accidentally blowing away the "unused" references to the needed plugins own dependencies.
2. **Post-build copying (with pre-build "pull")**: For a brief period of time, a senior team member set all the plugin projects to xcopy their outputs output themselves to a known "DependencyInjection" folder as post-build events.  Projects that needed those plugins would have pre-build events, xcopying each desired plugin to their own output directories.  While this meant that the plugin projects "rightly" had no knowledge of where they might be used, this caused two major headaches.  First, any time one made a change in a plugin project, they had to separately build (in sequence) the plugin project and then the executable project they would test it in (to get the files to copy over). Rebuild all would be more convenient but far too slow.  Second, the continuous integration build would have to have been reconfigured since it compiled everything all in one directory and only cared if everything built successfully.
3. **Post-build copying (push)**: The present solution started with xcopy and now mostly uses robocopy in post-build events of the plugin projects to copy needed files directly to the plugin folders of the executable projects that use them.  This works fairly well in that if one makes a change in a plugin, one can go straight to running with the debugger.  Also, the CI build doesn't break, and users disabling certain "optional" plugin projects for various builds don't get build errors from missing references.  This still seems hackish, and is cumbersome to maintain in all the separate post-build windows, which are rather small and can't be expanded.  When executable projects get moved from a project restructure or renamed, we don't find out about broken references until the next day after hearing results from the overnight automated testing.
4. **"Dummy" projects with references**: One idea that was briefly tossed about involved making empty projects for each of the different executable build configurations and going back to the hard references method on those.  Each would use its own references to gather up the plugins and their dependencies.  They would also have a reference to the actual executable and copy it over.  Then, if one wanted to run a particular executable in a particular configuration, you'd run its dummy project.  This one seemed particularly bloated and was never attempted.
5. **NuGet**: In my limited familiarity with NuGet, this seems like a good fit for using packages, except I wouldn't know how to implement that internal to one solution.  We've talked about breaking up the solution, but many members of the team are strongly opposed to that.  Is using NuGet with packages coming from within the same solution possible?

What are best practices for a situation like this?  Is there a better solution to managing dependencies of reflected dependencies like this than any of the above, or is a refinement of one of the above the best choice?

Comment: Do each developer need to constantly have all 100 assemblies (Debug mode) locally to test and develop, or are you looking for a *smart* way to get only a fraction of the 100 assemblies on the developer machine, just enough to let him test and develop its current job?  To give my opinion I'd need to know if you are seeking for first or second scenario.

Comment: Strictly speaking, one wouldn't necessarily need literally every project, but definitely the majority of them at any given time.  Fortunately, not everything is by reflection, but what isn't may also be itself a dependency of something that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I assume in this answer that each developer needs to constantly have all 100 assemblies (Debug mode) locally to do its job (develop, compile, smoke test, run automatic tests).

You are mentioning that RebuildAll takes long time. Generally this symptom is caused by too many assemblies + build process not rationalized. So the first thing to do is to try to merge the 100 assemblies into as few assemblies as possible and avoid using things like `Copy Local = true`. The effect will be a much faster (like 10x) RebuildAll process. Keep in mind that assemblies are physical artefacts and that they are useful only for physical things (like plug-in, loading on-demand, test/app separation...). I wrote a white-book that details my thoughts on the topic: http://www.ndepend.com/WhiteBooks.aspx

[Partitioning code base through .NET assemblies and Visual Studio projects (8 pages)](http://www.ndepend.com/Res/NDependWhiteBook_Assembly.pdf)

- Common valid and invalid reasons to create an assembly
- Increase Visual Studio solution compilation performance (up to x10 faster)
- Organize the development environment

In the white-book advice's, one of idea is to avoid referencing project but to reference assemblies instead. This way it becomes your responsibility to fill *Project > right click > Project Dependencies* that will define the *Project > right click > Project Build Order*. If you decide to keep dealing with 100 assemblies, defining this setting represents an effort, but as a bonus a high-level (executable) project can depend on a library only used by reflection and this will solve your problem.

Did you measure the [Lines of Code in terms of # of PDB sequences points](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#NbLinesOfCode)? I estimate that until the limit 200K to 300K doing a RebuildAll (with optimization described in the white-book) should take 5 to 10 seconds (on a decent laptop) and it remains acceptable. If your code base is very large and goes beyond this limit, you'll need to break my first assumption and find a way that a developer doesn't need all assemblies to do its job (in which case we can talk about this further).

*Disclaimer: This answer references resources from the site of the tool NDepend that I created and now manage its development.*

Answer (score 1):

I have been in a situation like yours. We had almost 100 projects. We too were using `MEF` and `System.AddIn`. In the beginning we had a few solutions. I was working on the core solution that included the core assemblies and their tests. Each plug-in category in a separate solution, that included contracts, implementation (some plug-ins had more than one implementation) and tests, plus some test host as well as the core assemblies. At some later point we added a solution that included all projects and after trying a few of the approaches you mention we decided to do the following:

1. Keep the references that are mandatory,
2. All executable projects were set to output to common locations (one for debug and one for release configurations),
3. All projects that should not be referenced were set to output to these common locations,
4. All projects that were referenced by others, were left unchanged and each reference was set with `Copy Local = true`.
5. Tests were left unchanged.

Although building all was slow, we didn't have any other problems. Of course having almost 100 projects is a sign that the design is probably too modular and as *Patrick* advises, we should have tried to compact it.

Anyway, you could try this approach in a couple of hours and perhaps instead of setting `Copy Local = true`, try to set the output folder of all projects mentioned in 4 to have their output set to the common locations. We didn't know that this setting will slow down the build process as *Patrick* mentions.

PS. We never tried using `NuGet` because we didn't have enough resources and time to experiment with it. It looked promising though.

Answer (score 0):

We are starting up a new project and I am looking for the "best practices" solution of this similar problem. For us, we can divide the projects into two categories 1) The Platform assemblies, which provide common set of services across the board and 2) Verticals which would be perform business specific functions.

In the past we have used a Visual Studio plug-in with a simple UI that allow developers to specify a common assemblies path to copy the output assemblies and then reference all assemblies (whereever they reside in a different solution) from the common assemblies folder.

I am looking at NUGET but the sheer work you have to do to created and maintain NUGET packages is punitive.

It's a very common scenario and would be really interested to see how others have addressed it.